# Sounds no longer working on Xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, compiz, 14.04, laptop

I was messing around with Compiz-related settings (something else I cannot get to work, no matter what I try) and after a restart my sound was no longer working. There seems to be two output devices now listed in my settings. I'm fairly certain the HMDI related one should not be there. There is no HDMI device connected to this laptop and there never has been.

[image: Outputs in my Sound Settings]

Any help is much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried retasking your jacks? Try this software and try overriding your jacks or speakers as output and see if it works http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/turn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu